# how to send and receive soap messages in attribute name/value format?

Tags: web-services, soap

What needs to be set in a web service so that soap messages are sent and received in param attribute format?  For example, I need to send soap requests with parameters in this attribute name/value format:

```
<param name="controller_name">CPA Central</param>
```

and receive them in a similar attribute name/value format:

```
<attribute name="channel_number">1</attribute>
```

I've googled literally for 14 hours and cannot find how to do it!  I would be so appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it.  Seems ridiculous that you have to intercept the outgoing soap message and reformat it, rather than creating it in the correct format to begin with.  But if your forced to use magic black boxes like JAX-WS like I was, your stuck with the auto-format they provide apparently.

```
public class InneoquestLogicalHandler implements LogicalHandler<LogicalMessageContext> {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(InneoquestSoapHandler.class);

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(LogicalMessageContext context) {
        boolean isResponse = (Boolean)context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if(!isResponse){
            logger.debug("InneoquestLogicalHandler.handleMessage(): this is a soap request");
        }
        else {
            logger.debug("InneoquestLogicalHandler.handleMessage(): this is a soap response");
            try {
                try {
                    transform(context);
                } catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InneoquestLogicalHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (SOAPException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InneoquestLogicalHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } catch (TransformerException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InneoquestLogicalHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    return true;
    }

    private void transform(LogicalMessageContext context) throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException, SOAPException {
        LogicalMessage msg = context.getMessage();
        Source source = msg.getPayload();
        Transformer xFormer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        xFormer.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
        DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
        xFormer.transform(source,result);
        Document doc = (Document) result.getNode();
        transformNodeList(doc,doc.getChildNodes());
        source = new DOMSource(doc);
        msg.setPayload(source);
    }

    private void transformNodeList(Document doc, NodeList nodeList) {
        for (int i=0; i< nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node childNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (childNode.getNodeName().equals("channel_number")) {
                Element elem = (Element)childNode;
                doc.renameNode(elem, elem.getNamespaceURI(), "attribute");
                elem.setAttribute("name", "channel_number");
            }
            else if (childNode.getNodeName().equals("count")) {
                Element elem = (Element)childNode;
                doc.renameNode(elem, elem.getNamespaceURI(), "response");
                elem.setAttribute("rows", elem.getTextContent());
                elem.setTextContent("");
                elem.setAttribute("type", "success");
            }

            NodeList children = childNode.getChildNodes();
            if (children != null) {
                transformNodeList(doc,children);
            }
        }
    }
```